# Использование веб камеры из С++

Tags: windows, web-camera, c++

Хочу написать приложение работающее с веб камерой. Интересует какие есть способы работы с ней? ОС будет  windows ХР, windows Vista и windowws 7. Можно ли писать в файл и т.д.? Есть ли завязки на производителей веб камер или на драйвера устройств?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Рекомендую ознакомиться с библиотекой [OpenCV](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV),  представляющей возможности обработки изображений.  В примерах можно найти работу с веб-камерой (samples/c/facedetect.c - поиск лиц на изображении с веб-камеры, демонстрирующий возможность захвата изображения с камеры с помощью модуля HighGUI).  Если драйвер камеры правильно работает, то принципиальной разницы нет, веб-камера представляется обычным интерфейсом устройства DirectShow. В интернете можно найти много материалов с готовыми примерами по OpenCV.